# 2 Progress bars with different colors

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I've made 2 progress bars with succes! But here's the hard part, I'm trying to give both of them a different color with CSS styling by using classes on the progress bars and styling them in CSS but it won't change color. I want the first bar to have the color `#c30000` and the second bar to have the color `#1eff00`. But whenever I add the classes both of the bars go back to the default state of progress bars without styling.

```css
.progress1 {
  progress {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  }
  progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: #c30000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  }
  progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background-color: #c30000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  }
}

.progress2 {
  progress {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  }
  progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: #1eff00;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  }
  progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background-color: #1eff00;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress1"><progress value="50" max="100"></progress></div>
<br />
<div class="progress2"><progress value="25" max="100"></progress></div>
```

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS? If so tag and mention it accordingly. For pure CSS, nesting of selectors would be invalid.

Comment: If I write your SASS/LESS as normal CSS it works flawlessly for me. I also cleaned up your CSS-code from 49 lines down to 23 lines: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/oNerKpg

Comment: @tacoshy when dealing with specific browser selector, you should not combine the selector because each is targeting a specific browser while all the other will fail. If you combine them, they will all fail

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you for the heads up. I didn't knew that.

Comment: @tacoshy I figured it out! https://codepen.io/s-sal73/pen/NWvQKGL

Comment: @HelloHello please respond to the question with your answer and explanation and mark it as answered